# Why isn't this code returning a floating point number? (python 2.7.3)

Tags: python-2.7

Hi so I just got into python a few days ago and I was working on this assignment from a book. I am supposed to find the property tax and assessment tax on a piece of land.

```
def assessment_value(property_value):
    assessed_value = property_value * 0.60
    print "Your assessed property value is $%d." % assessed_value
    property_tax(assessed_value)

def property_tax(assessed_value):
    tax = (assessed_value / 100.0) * 0.64
    print "Your property tax is $%d." % tax

def main():
    property_value = float(raw_input("Please enter the value of your property. "))
    assessment_value(property_value)

main()
```

When everything runs using 10000 as the property value the result I get is 38 instead of 38.4. What confuses me is if I do float(60) * 0.64 it returns the value I want which is 38.4. But if I set the value of tax to be 60 it returns 38. Sorry if this is an extremely simple question as I said I am new to python and I have no one to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the value as an integer `%d` within the string. You would need to use `%f`.
See [docs for String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `%d`. For float you can use `%f` or `%.2f`

Comment: Thanks I knew it had to be something simple. But I didn't think it would be that simple. I really really appreciate the help from you guys.